# Show continuity using the difference quotient.

Tags: derivatives, continuity

I am trying to show that $f$ is continuous and differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$. My idea is to show that the difference quotient ($\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0)}{h}$) exists, the function is differentiable and therefore has to be continuous.

Because I find it sometimes difficult using the epsilon delta criterion to show continuity.

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be given by $f(x) = x \cdot \sqrt{\vert x \vert}$.

$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(x+h) \cdot \sqrt{\vert x + h\vert} - x\cdot \sqrt{\vert x \vert}}{h} \cdot \frac{(x+h) \cdot \sqrt{\vert x + h\vert} + x\cdot \sqrt{\vert x \vert}}{(x+h) \cdot \sqrt{\vert x + h\vert} + x\cdot \sqrt{\vert x \vert}}
= \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{(x+h)^3 - \left(x\cdot \sqrt{\vert x \vert}\right)^2}{h\left((x+h)\sqrt{\vert x + h \vert} + x\cdot\sqrt{\vert x \vert}\right)} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{h(3x^2 + 3xh + h^2)}{h\left((x+h)\sqrt{\vert x + h \vert} + x\cdot\sqrt{\vert x \vert}\right)} = \frac{3x^2}{2 x \sqrt{\vert x \vert}} = \frac{3x}{2\sqrt{\vert x \vert}}$

Now when I calculate the derivative the usual way I get:
$f'(x) = \frac{3x^2}{2\left|x\right|\sqrt{\left|x\right|}}$ (using the common derivative $\frac{d}{dx} \vert x \vert = \frac{x}{\vert x \vert}$)
Here we have the absolute value of $x$ in the denominator.

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take $x\ne 0$
$$\left(x\sqrt{|x|}\right)^{'}=\left(|x|\text{sign}(x)\sqrt{|x|}\right)^{'}=\left(|x|^{\frac{3}{2}}\text{sign}(x)\right)^{'}=\frac{3}{2}|x|^{\frac{1}{2}}\text{sign}(x)=\frac{3}{2}|x|^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{x}{|x|}=\frac{3x}{2\sqrt{\vert x \vert}}$$